# The argument taken order of curried functions in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Normally, we write a function like this

```
let abs_diff x y = abs (x-y)
```

also we can have a `curried version`:

```
let abs_diff = fun x -> fun y -> abs(x-y)
```

---

I write this question here just want to confirm that I understand *currying* correctly.

Here is my understanding:

1. `let abs_diff = fun x -> fun y -> abs(x-y)` actually returns a function with one parameter which is `fun y -> abs (x-y)` and inside it, x is the parameter
2. So, when we apply `abs_diff 5 6`, it firsts takes the first argument `5`, returns a function `fun y -> abs (5-y)`, then continue to apply to argument `6`, so the final result is `(fun y -> abs (5-y)) 6`

Am I correct?

Furthermore, to deal with an function application, is OCaml interpreter like utop, ocaml doing like point 2 above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the two writing

```
let abs_diff x y = abs (x-y)
let abs_diff = fun x -> fun y -> abs(x-y)
```

are equivalent. They both define the very same function of type

```
val abs_diff : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

An uncurried version would have been

```
# let abs_diff (x,y) = abs(x-y);;
val abs_diff : int * int -> int = <fun>
```

that is a function taking one parameter namely a couple `(x,y)` of type `int*int`.

---

It is not clear to me what you mean by

> and inside it, x is the parameter

Do you mean that `x` is **replaced** by the parameter ?

---

What really is happening it that the call to `abs_diff 5` return a [**closure**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29), that is a function with some context. Something like

```
fun y -> abs (x-y)   where   x = 5
```

which is of course equivalent to

```
fun y -> abs (5-y)
```

Note that the compiler is able to optimize all this function manipulation to a simple function call if this is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add this:

Functions in OCaml are always curried. This can be strange for beginners.The confusion can be: when do I assign the function, and when the function result?

```
# let sayhello  = print_endline "hello!";;
hello!
val sayhello : unit = ()
# let hello ()  = print_endline "hello!";;
val hello : unit -> unit = <fun>
# let h = hello;;
val h : unit -> unit = <fun>
# h ();;
hello!
- : unit = ()
```

`sayhello` is assigned the result of the execution of `print_endline`, which is ().

`hello` is a function that takes () as parameter.

`h` is now the same function, not executed. It is executed if the parameter is there.

I hope I made this clearer. One must definitely learn to perfectly read the type information the toplevel prints out.

One more thing to syntax:

```
let f1 x y = x - y;;
let f2 = fun x y -> x - y;;
let f3 = function x -> function y -> x - y;;
```

These definitions result in the same function. You can use `fun` with more than one parameter, but not `function`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The normal way to look at it is that a function `'a -> 'b -> 'c` is curried, while a function `'a * 'b -> 'c` is not curried. Both can be defined in OCaml.

Comment: Because `'a * 'b` is the type of a pair, normally written (a, b), and a pair is one parameter. I think I've got it.

Comment: @Str.: That doesn't make sense. Curried vs. uncurried is a conceptual distinction, not a semantic distinction. It is precisely the distinction for the programmer when conceptually needing multiple arguments, between choosing to write a function that takes an argument and returns a function taking the rest of the arguments, or to take all the arguments together. You can write multi-parameter functions as curried or uncurried in any language.

Comment: @newacct Are you referring to my answer or my comment?

Comment: @Str.: both. mainly the assertion that "Functions in OCaml are always curried.", which JeffreyScofield responded to.

Comment: @newacct I am shure you can look at it from different angles. But currying is in OCaml not only a conceptual distinction, but a concrete internal structure. In OCaml only functions with one parameter exist (what you define with the `function` keyword). This is the basis for what in a stricter sense is called _currying_: fixing one or more parameters of a function. I adhere to the term usage like in the OCaml 4.01 PDF refman page 110 near the bottom and esp. page 273.

Comment: @Str.: Yes, functions in OCaml always have exactly one parameter formally. How is that relevant to currying?

Comment: @newacct OCaml calls this _curried_.

Comment: @Str.: No it doesn't. You are misreading it. Nowhere does it say that any function "is curried". That wouldn't even make any sense, because "curried" is not a property of a function; it's a design pattern for how to write functions when you want multiple inputs. "Currying" only makes sense with respect to when you have multiple "arguments". OCaml functions have exactly one argument.

Comment: @newacct Following your definition you are (of course) right. But this does not preclude a wider use of the term. And I can't see where I am misreading the manual. Maybe others would like to support one or the other point of view, though SO does not lend itself well to discussions.